# NetBeans can't run maven

Tags: java, netbeans, maven-3

I tried to open a netbeans waven project, when I tried to build the project, it failed with the following message,
Cannot run program "C:\apache-maven-3.2.3\bin\mvn.bat" (in directory "F:\my_project\Source\Application\main"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
I am sure the mvn.bat exists in C:\apache-maven-3.2.3\bin directory. I also tried the bundled maven within netbeans, I got the same error.

Has anyone seen such problems?

Thanks